# WP Comment Count PHP Conditional

Tags: php, wordpress, count, comments, conditional-statements

I have some data I'd like to display only when there is one or more comments to a post. And I would like to display nothing when there are 0 comments.

The logic is this:

if comment count > 0 { do this }
else { }

If some one could help me out with PHP snippet for this type of thing it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nr_comments = get_comments_number( $post_id );

if($nr_comments > 0){
   //we have comments and do this
}
else{
   //we don't have any comments yet and do something else
}
```

Note: This tag must be within The Loop.

Since this is whithin the loop you don't need the `$post_id`.

Comment: I may need to run this outside the loop, perhaps in a custom query, is there another method I should use for that?

Comment: If outside the loop give it the post id and it should its job.